# Cannot publish Power BI report to local Report Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, powerbi

We have just installed a local instance of the **Power BI report server** on our **SSRS 2016 server**.

It runs fine, can browse the directories via a browser. But when trying to publish from the desktop application we get the error:

> an error occurred while attempting to save the report to power bi report server.

If trying to upload a `.pbix` file through a web browser we get this error "There was an error uploading your `.pbix` file. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file".

The suggestion when searching says the Service Account being used (set via the Report Server Configuration Manager) must have local admin rights and rights to the database. I have tried several ways of doing this and still nothing works.

Comment: Check this [Can’t save Power BI Report to Power BI Server](https://blog.devoworx.net/2019/01/19/missing-save-as-power-bi-report-server-in-power-bi-desktop/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSRS 2016 does not support publishing power bi reports locally.

You have to upgrade your SSRS instance to SSRS 2017

It also comes as a separated install package now.

Link for download: [Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Reporting Services](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55252)

---

**Update by @taterhead:**

Power BI files to be uploaded by a custom Power BI Desktop that matches Power BI Report Server: [Install Power BI Desktop optimized for Power BI Report Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/install-powerbi-desktop)

Comment: Thanks. Now thinking I'm going to install it on a server on it's own. Better to install a SQL Server 2017 instance then?

Comment: SSRS 2017 is a really standalone now and does not require to have latest SQL Server 2017 as a data engine for SSRS databases. Therefore, you can upgrade ssrs instance only

Comment: Completely fresh Server 2012 server, SQL 2017 installed, Power BI Local Server installed and still the same error!

Comment: @Taterhead provided an excellent answer about client and server tool mismatch

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use [Power Bi Desktop Optimized for Power Bi Report Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/install-powerbi-desktop) (yes its a separate client).  The release of this client coincides with the release of Power Bi Report Server.  Both were recently released in March 2018.  Before that, the previous release was October 2017.

Try opening your report inside of this Power Bi Desktop Optimized for Power Bi Report Server, ensure your report is working according to your requirements and then save, and upload this file to Report Server.  There are some [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/install-powerbi-desktop#considerations-and-limitations) on reports that are released to Report Server that you need to consider (no R Visuals, ARCGIS Maps, and others.).  But most of the functionality will work on Report Server.

[This thread](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Report-Server/Unable-to-upload-Pbix-files/td-p/315948) has a user with the same error as yours, and using the Power Bi Desktop Optimized for Report Server solved the problem for that user.

Comment: If I were in charge of the Power Bi developers, I would request they enhance this error message to ask "was **Power Bi Desktop Optimized for Power Bi Report Server** was used to author this report?" and provide a download link or something similar.

Comment: Yes that would be helpful but I do have the correct version of Power BI Report Server

Comment: which version do you have?  You can still download the corresponding client.  Use the link provided by the server - see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/install-powerbi-desktop#download-and-install-power-bi-desktop

Comment: for Oct 2017 - use this link:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56136

Comment: It looks like there was a mismatch in the versions of the client and server being used. Now both on March 2018 and can upload reports. Thanks everyone for their help.

Comment: Please up-vote all answers that helped and make the question answered