# Save as Power BI Report Server for publish

Tags: sql-server, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I tried to publish a report with SSRS BI.

I used `Power BI desktop May 2019` and Report server `ver 15.0.1104.310`

1. IE run with **run as administrator**
2. Power BI run with **run as administrator**
3. Reporting Server Configuration run with **run as administrator**
4. Set Web service URL
5. Set database and test it
6. Set web portal URL
7. Generate a report in Power BI Desktop and save it in a folder
8. now I tried to save as report by portal URL but catch error :

> an error occurred while attempting to save the report to power bi report server

[image]

Set new report server `http://reporting-power/ReportsPBI` this link work well on IE

When save as this report ask a question for set file name I set `Test.pbix` and click on OK button. save process start and shown above error message.

Also I tried to create a new folder on Power BI Report server and save as report on this folder, and again received above error again.

I search problem and just find this link for [SSRS 2016 does not support publishing power bi reports locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649004/cannot-publish-power-bi-report-to-local-report-server) but I used 2019 and received same error.

Comment: Are you using SSRS 2019 or Power BI Report Server?  Only Power BI Report Server supports publishing Power BI Reports.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/install-report-server#:~:text=Power%20BI%20Report%20Server%201%20Find%20the%20location,launch%20the%20Reporting%20Services%20Configuration%20Manager.%20See%20More.  And there's a seperate download for Power BI Desktop for Power BI Report Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/install-powerbi-desktop

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes David, I used PBIRS. How to use this model with built in account. my problem solve when I change service account to Domain/User . but when I don't have Domain service can I use built-in account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be change service account. I set use built-in account.
But the **service account** used in Report server Configuration Manager was not a local admin.

With a user that is a local **administrator** on the server, we were able to get PBI Reports working on PBIRS.
[image]